# R function to to search and replace text in a column

Tags: r, function, replace

#I'm seeking to write code that takes a column with character values (e.g. ALA3=VAL20) and converts it to a specific single letter corresponding to that three letter code (e.g. A3=V20). I attempted using the following function, but seem to be having trouble:

```
    substitute_codes <- function(data, col_name) {
  # Create a dictionary of the code substitutions
  code_dict <- c("ALA" = "A", "ARG" = "R", "ASN" = "N", "ASP" = "D",
                 "CYS" = "C", "GLU" = "E", "GLN" = "Q", "GLY" = "G",
                 "HIS" = "H", "ILE" = "I", "LEU" = "L", "LYS" = "K",
                 "MET" = "M", "PHE" = "F", "PRO" = "P", "SER" = "S",
                 "THR" = "T", "TRP" = "W", "TYR" = "Y", "VAL" = "V")
  
  # Apply the substitutions using gsub()
  data[[col_name]] <- gsub(paste(names(code_dict), collapse = "|"), 
                           paste(code_dict, collapse = ""), 
                           data[[col_name]])
  
  return(data)
}
```

But I get results like the following from ALA3=VAL20 to  ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV3=ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV20

Comment: `stringr::str_replace_all("ALA3=VAL20", code_dict)` gets `"A3=V20"`

Answer (score 1):

As Darren Tsai points out in the comments, we can just use the `cdoe_dict` in `str_replace_all()`:

```r
library(stringr)

set.seed(123)
x <- sample(names(code_dict), 10)
y <- sample(names(code_dict), 10)
my_string <- paste0(x, sample(10), "=", y, sample(10))
my_string

#>  [1] "PRO4=PHE9"  "TYR1=CYS10" "PHE3=HIS2"  "ASN7=ASN7"  "ILE5=GLY3" 
#>  [6] "ARG10=ILE4" "GLU8=GLN1"  "LEU2=PRO6"  "CYS9=TRP5"  "ASP6=THR8"

str_replace_all(my_string, 
                code_dict)
#>  [1] "P4=F9"  "Y1=C10" "F3=H2"  "N7=N7"  "I5=G3"  "R10=I4" "E8=Q1"  "L2=P6" 
#>  [9] "C9=W5"  "D6=T8"
```

For more complex replacements, we could a custom function inside `str_replace_all()` as replacement argument. The custom function below `shorten_str` just uses a classical lookup with base R's `match()`, but we could add any kind of complexity here.

```r
library(stringr)

# our dictionary
code_dict <- c("ALA" = "A", "ARG" = "R", "ASN" = "N", "ASP" = "D",
               "CYS" = "C", "GLU" = "E", "GLN" = "Q", "GLY" = "G",
               "HIS" = "H", "ILE" = "I", "LEU" = "L", "LYS" = "K",
               "MET" = "M", "PHE" = "F", "PRO" = "P", "SER" = "S",
               "THR" = "T", "TRP" = "W", "TYR" = "Y", "VAL" = "V")

# let's create a toy string
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(names(code_dict), 10)
y <- sample(names(code_dict), 10)

my_string <- paste0(x, sample(10), "=", y, sample(10))
my_string
#>  [1] "PRO4=PHE9"  "TYR1=CYS10" "PHE3=HIS2"  "ASN7=ASN7"  "ILE5=GLY3" 
#>  [6] "ARG10=ILE4" "GLU8=GLN1"  "LEU2=PRO6"  "CYS9=TRP5"  "ASP6=THR8"

# custom function to replace string
shorten_str <- function(abr) {
  code_dict[match(abr, names(code_dict))]
}

# implementation with `str_replace_all()`
str_replace_all(my_string, 
                paste(names(code_dict), collapse = "|"),
                shorten_str)
#>  [1] "P4=F9"  "Y1=C10" "F3=H2"  "N7=N7"  "I5=G3"  "R10=I4" "E8=Q1"  "L2=P6" 
#>  [9] "C9=W5"  "D6=T8"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>